# Reference Error: calling class method in super() typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, solid-principles

I am not able to call someMethod, it gives error

> ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before
> accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor\

```
class BaseClass{
//some properties here I want to return whoever extends BaseClass
}

class ChildClass extend BaseClass{
    constructor(){
        super(
            this.someMethod();
        )
    }
    
    someMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `this.someMethod()` inside of `super()`?

Comment: If you want `someMethod` to calculate the argument that should be passed to `super()`, you'll need to change it so it's not an instance method, (e.g. a `static` or global function)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel As already stated in the answer and in the comment above I wanted to do some calculations and pass that to the base class. 
What now I am doing is calling super with arguments passed as a reference and changing that reference in derived class afterward. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor, you have to call `super()` before you can use `this`:

```
class BaseClass{
//some properties here I want to return whoever calls ChildClass
}

class ChildClass extend BaseClass{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.someMethod();
    }
    
    someMethod() {}
}
```

There is no permitted structure for `super(this.someMethod())` because you can't use `this` before you've called `super(...)`.  There is something like `super.someMethod()` which lets you call base class methods (without your local override), but that's not a substitute for calling `super()` in your constructor.

You can call `super(someArgs)` with arguments if you want and that would be whatever arguments you want to be passed to the base class constructor.  But, you can't use `this` before doing so.

Comment: That's quite I was struggling with. Kudos!!